# Problems while opening .tab file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tab

I'm currently struggling with adding an OS 1:25k (.tab) to my workspace in QGIS. 
It comes up with the message

> is not a valid or recognised data source

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please refrain from posting two questions at once, since this makes answering and finding the correct answer later too complicated. Also add information about your data on the people working for your organisation, and what you tried so far in order to display the names accordingly to your criteria.

Comment: OS 1:25k is usually raster are there any tif,jpgs,pngs of the data? This sound very do-able in QGIS.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise I couldn't ask more than one question...their information would only be their name and title of their roles in our organisation, but I want to plot this onto a parish.
I've tried to several tutorials but never seem to work. I'm not very good at GIS and difficult when I'm the only person in the building that can vaguely even understand GIS!

Comment: I have tried to open the OS 1:25k as a raster and it still won't work. I know it is do-able as I've uploaded other data into QGIS before but for some reason this won't open :( 
There is a tif version of the data. Problem is, it's all old from when we had a GIS department before so the data is all mixed up. But the one I know that works just won't upload.

Comment: Any time you have an **and** in the title, you're going to be violating the One question per Question policy, which is stated in the [Tour]: `Your most important question is important to us. - Asking one, and only one, important question within your Question helps attract prompt and clear Answers. - Your other questions are just as easy to research/ask separately!`

Comment: So this is now an example of why asking two questions in one Question is such a problem. One of your questions was answered, and you've changed the question to ask the other one, making the existing answer a *non sequitur*.

Comment: So, I came onto this forum for support and help and all you've done is put me down and made me feel inadequate. I will be leaving this forum thoroughly disappointed in the bullying attitude towards people who are new to this. Thank you to 'Mapperz' who actually did try and help me.

Answer (score 2):

For the labeling side of your question:

In QGIS to Label the Parish with a rule 
(In this case only label Tormorden CP)

[image]

The code is in the rule-based setting

```
"PARISH"  =  'TODMORDEN CP'
```

You can add more rules to accommodate all your labels you want to show.